# Timestamp in SQL Server in readable format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I have created a column in a SQL Server database which records the timestamp. But the timestamp is like this `0x000000000000177F`. Is there any way convert this timestamp into date&time (readable) ?

Comment: Well, the `timestamp` in SQL Server does not contain a date and time. It's something entirely different (and deprecated as well if I'm not mistaken). If you want a date and time use `datetime2`

Answer (score -1):

`Timestamp` in SQL Server (What a poor choice for a name it is!) is a synonym for the `rowversion` data type - and, as a_horse_with_no_name wrote in his comment - is deprecated and may be removed in newer versions of SQL Server.

From the [rowversion (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation page:

> `timestamp` is the synonym for the `rowversion` data type and is subject to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use `rowversion` instead of `timestamp` wherever possible.
>
> The Transact-SQL `timestamp` data type is **different** from the `timestamp` data type defined in the ISO standard.

(emphasis mine.)

Also:

> **Note**
>   The `timestamp` syntax is deprecated. This feature is in maintenance mode and may be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: Minor, minor nitpick, but the docs merely say it *may* be removed in a future version, not that it will be. The vast majority of features marked as deprecated in SQL Server have in fact not been removed since their deprecation marker went up, and whether or not `timestamp` will really ever go the way of the dodo is anyone's guess.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, you are correct, as usual :-). Fixed.